# parsing fcinfo output in cmdshell

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell

I have the following output which I am trying to parse like so

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> fcinfo /details

  adapter: com.microsoft-Virtual Fibre Channel HBA-0
 node_wwn: c0:03:ff:00:00:ff:ff:00
   fabric: 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 port_wwn: c0:03:ff:58:b6:20:00:02
 osdevice: \\.\Scsi1:
    venid: x0
   prodid: x0
```

But I see not a clean parse using the below code

```
my $listHBAs = `fcinfo /details`;
my @lines = split(/\n/,$listHBAs);
my $wwns;
foreach (@lines) {
     if($_ =~ /port_wwn \s+ : (.*)$/){
         &runSsh($arrayIP, "$ig --wwpn $1");
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Linux when the command is fairly clearly being run on Windows?  You look as though you're using extended format for the regex but you haven't added the `/x` at the end of the regex.  You also demand a space with `\s+` but your sample output shows no space: `m/port_wwn \s* : \s* (.*)$/x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp doesn't match output you provide and you're somewhat complicating things with unnecessary preprocessing (i.e. `split`).

```
my $listHBAs = `fcinfo /details`;
while ($listHBAs =~ /port_wwn\s*:\s*(\S*)$/gm) {
    &runSsh($arrayIP, "$ig --wwpn $1");
}
```

If you exepect just one `port_wwn`, `if` will do just as fine as `while`.